# Java Synchronization - Wait for n threads to arrive

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, semaphore

Let's suppose that there is a barber and a customer. The barber sleeps until 5 customers arrive, and when the 5th customer awakes the barber and he starts doing his job.

The sequence order is this: awake -> sit inside barbershop if there is space (5 people max) and wait for your turn -> sit on chair -> pay -> if you are the last customer and nobody is waiting inside/outside the barber falls asleep.

How do I approach this problem?

My attempt: http://pastebin.com/G0CzJBVG

However, it is flawed.

Comment: add your attempts, please

Comment: @AndrewTobilko done.

Comment: Please add your code inline, not as a pastebin link. questions shouldn't depend on external links.

Comment: @NathanHughes 400 lines?

Comment: read about [how to make a mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). wouldn't think this takes 400 lines to do. also give an explicit error instead of "it is flawed".

Comment: A race condition happens in my code.

Comment: "a race condition happens" is not an explicit error.  An explicit error would be a complete stack trace if your program throws an exception, or a compiler error message if your program does not compile, or "this is the output I expected ..., but this is the output I got instead ..."

Comment: I am not asking what's wrong with my code, but what is wrong with my approach to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, once the barber is awake is starts to cut hair for the customers, and has to finish the first one before going to the next one, so you need a mechanism to make sure that the customers are processed in order they came. Also, while he is working,other customers might come, and he will not stop and go to sleep until there is no one in the barbershop.

My suggestion is the following:

- you will have two threads: one thread is for the barber, doing his job, the other for the customer checkin;
- to preserve the order, use an `ArrayBlockingQueue` on which the second thread keeps adding elements as the customers are coming to the barbershop
- to make sure the barber only starts working when there 5 customers, use a `CountDownLatch(5)` on which the second thread is calling `countDown()` every time it is adding a new customer, but only if `getCount() != 0`, while the first thread is holding a call to `await()`, before it starts reading elements from the `ArrayBlockingQueue`
- every time the first thread finishes to process an element, checks the queue and if there are no more elements in the queue, it re-initialize the `countDownLatch(5)` and calls `await()` to block until the queue is full again.
- finally, in order to limit the number of customers in the barbershop, create the `ArrayBlockingQueue` with a capacity of 5.

I hope it answers your problem.